# How to support css background image property for buttons in opera

Tags: html, css, background-image, opera

css doesn't support background  image property for buttons in opera web browser.I used  css background  image property for my own creation but it's doesn't appear when i use opera browser.when i use firefox it appear well...   but i saw button background images support some websites in opera properly how can i do it in opera web browser?

ex: http://ikman.lk/en/ads-in-gampaha  (see this web site's search button image...it appear well in opera)

Answer (score 0):

The website you link to is simply using a button element with a span inside. The span has a CSS-gradient background. Inside the span is an i element, which has a search icon background image. They probably used this setup not because of problems with opera, but because they're using an image sprite and the nested i element could be made so small the other parts of the sprite image don't show even though the button is larger.

The button isn't doing any background-related stuff for the gradient or the icon, so it doesn't matter if Opera supports this or not.

By the way, Opera is using the Blink engine now, so if Chromium and Chrome support the property on buttons, so should Opera since version 15.

Answer (score 0):

This icon is not a direct css background image of the button But of an `I` elemnet that is placed inside the button.

here is the html:

```
<button class="btn large search-btn" type="submit">
    <span>
         <i class="ico-search-btn"></i>
    </span>
</button>
```

and then they added a background to `.ico-search-btn`.

Did you tried it this way?

Comment: i didn't.. can you give some live demo